# get result of two query with one query - mysql

Tags: mysql

```
$sql ="select * from user limit 5";
```

is there any way that i can get limited number of results but with total results without limit.

Basically i want result of below two queries in one single query.

```
query 1 : select count(*) from user
query 2 : select * from user LIMIT 5
```

is that possible without any sub query?

Comment: `COUNT()` is an aggregate function. That implies that it merges rows. I do not think that it is possible in an effective way.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *, '' as total from user limit 5
UNION
select *,count(*) as total from user group by id>0
```

Comment: select * from user limit 5
union
select count(*) as total from user

I have tried this, but giving error..... Is there anything wrong?

Comment: make sure its `union select *,count(*)` not just `union select count(*)`

Comment: select *, '' as total from user limit 5
UNION
select *,count(*) as total from user
 This works but not proper data.... Anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but the answer can help someone else.

It is possible to tell MySql to return only the first 5 results AND calculate the total number, using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, as explained here http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/mysql-get-total-number-of-rows-when-using-limit.html

You issue two queries, but in the first one you hint the db engine to calculate and keep the total number of rows that would be returned without the LIMIT clause

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
select  *,
        (select count(*) from user) TotalUsers
from    user 
LIMIT 5
```

Or maybe

```
select  user.*,
        TotalUsers.TotalCnt
from    user,
        (select count(*) TotalCnt from user) TotalUsers
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: is there any way that I can eliminate these sub query? can this be done in one single query?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, and as far as I know it just isn't possible.. Stick with two queries, it's fast and clear.

Answer (score 0):

single query not possible if without join or union, however, you can try something like

```
select sql_calc_found_rows * from user limit 5;
select found_rows();  <-- total from first query
```